# Issue while sending mail using outlook 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, outlook

I have been facing one issue while sending mail using outlook 2010 in my application.

When I click button to execute mail functionality, one dialog box appears which is asking user to allow or deny application to send mail using outlook account. If I allow then email will be sent successfully but if deny then I am getting  this error

> 'Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))'.

What is possible way to send mail without asking user for his approval.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do your job:

```
     app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
     f = ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
     Thread.Sleep(5000); // a bit of startup grace time.
```

The other way to do it is by getting Inspector object for newly created

```
     Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
     Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
     Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMsg.GetInspector;
```

The latter answer was published in [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.outlook.program_vba/lLJwbwwl-XU/gRuQYRpJtxEJ) originally for Outlook 2007 but it should work for Outlook 2010 too